# What kind of busses does the double-decker replace?

Tags: simcity-2013

The Double-Decker Bus Terminal (from the special edition) is called a "bus terminal" like the one that carries sims around the region, but in the tooltip there is no mention of any regional effect. So my question is: does it replace the shuttle depot or the bus terminal?? (in other words: does it work only in the city, or is it region-wide?) Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Double-decker Bus Terminal](http://www.simcityhub.com/transportation/double-decker-bus-terminal) fills the same role as the [Bus Terminal](http://www.simcityhub.com/transportation/bus-terminal).

The functionality is the same. Exceptions are that the double-decker:

- Has a capacity of 100 (compared to 80).
- Costs 800/hr (compared to 750).

As for regional effects:

- Workers can always commute to and from your city.
- A [Shuttle Bus Depot](http://www.simcityhub.com/transportation/shuttle-bus-depot) (the small one) allos them to do this more effectively (more people per vehicle, less traffic).
- A Bus Terminal (or Double-decker Bus Terminal) opens up for tourist transportation, to and from your city.

Its important to remember that all traffic is essentially opened up if *someone* places a Bus Terminal. When they do, you can just go ahead and place [Bus Stops](http://www.simcityhub.com/transportation/bus-stop) and get region-wide transport. A Bus Stop requires a Shuttle Bus Depot in your city **or** a Bus Terminal in the region.

Comment: Good block of info. Well beyond the question asked but good none the less! +1 for you!

Comment: Good info indeed! And it even has the answer to my question! Thanks much!

Comment: To clarify, can sims actually ride a shuttle bus to a different city?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals, I think so. They can ride their own cars to other cities. So I cant see why the buses wouldnt. But I know for sure that the buses do if you or anyone else have placed the Bus Terminal.

Comment: The Double-decker buses don't leave the city -- so it's actually a replacement for the Shuttle Bus Depot.

Comment: @user43524 strange, I've had double-deckers arrive in my city.